# Calling phone numbers programmatically [JAVA]

Tags: java, voip, telephony

I am developing a web application that need to have a feature to call phone numbers (like skype credit calls), can this be achieved by VOIP ? how does skype has implemented this feature? what are the correct technologies to use to implement this.

Can someone point me in the correct direction ? Thanks

Comment: Yes (VOIP). Microsoft proprietary information (call them and ask). Requests for off-site resources are off-topic.

Comment: Have you done some research about open source application using VOIP ? SO is not the place for this so you will probably not find any answer here.